# crop image in wrong area android

Tags: android, image, crop

I am making an app to crop image right after i press the take_picture button. 
I did it, but it crops in the yellow rectangle. What i want is the red rectangle. Here is the picture:
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P20Aw.png)

I don't know why this happen because i passed in the position and dimension of the red rectangle.
here is code which i used to crop image:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setRotate(90, (float) bitmap.getWidth() / 2, (float) bitmap.getHeight() / 2);
Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
cropBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(rotatedBitmap, (int)(rectangleView.point1.x),
                                                (int)(rectangleView.point1.y),
             (int)(Math.abs(rectangleView.point2.x - rectangleView.point1.x)),
             (int)(Math.abs(rectangleView.point2.y - rectangleView.point1.y)));

Intent it = new Intent();
it.putExtra("cropImage", cropBitmap);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, it);
finish();
```

rectangleView is the red rectangle.
point1 is top and left.
point2 is right and bottom.

how can i fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My guess would be views are being naughty. Try logging the different points  and compare against the rectangle positions.

Comment: Are you sure the bitmap size and the screen size are the same? It looks like you are taking in rectangles position on screen.

Comment: it's exactly like you said. I fixed it. 
Thank you so much for spending your time on my question Naveen Dissanayake and Sipty